# how to customize a key board shortcuts on windows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Can any one provide me with step by step algorithm to make a keyboard shortcut on 
windows 7.

Also kindly tell me that where the hibernation file resides in a computer , so that
I can make its shortcut too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hibernate shortcut, follow this:

1. Right-click on an empty spot on the Desktop
2. Choose “New-Shortcut” from the context menu
3. In the box labeled "Type the location of the item:" enter:
   %windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -h
4. Click "Next"
5. Enter a name for the shortcut and click "Finish"